# angular js add JSON to ng-list

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-nglist

I have 3 properties included JSON object array 'notes'.

```
$scope.notes = [
        {
            'type':'txt',
            'name': 'JohnHenry',
            'text':'Greeting',
        }
    ];
```

My input field is

```
`<input type="text" placeholder="Text here..." ng-model="note.input" ng-list="," ng-enter="addnote()">`
```

I will type in below text into input textfield.

```
"txt-Glen-Negotiate Price, num-Phil-0939876, met-DrWalh-1505"
```

type property is to display icon. I wish to get as below JSON

```
$scope.notes = [
        {
            'type':'txt',
            'name': 'JohnHenry',
            'text':'Greeting',
        },{
            'type':'txt',
            'name': 'Glen',
            'text':'negotiate price',
        },{
            'type':'num',
            'name': 'Phil',
            'text':'0939876',
        },{
            'type':'met',
            'name': 'DrWalh',
            'text':'1505',
        }
    ];
```

How to convert input ng-list text to JSON objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own directive

```
app.directive('jsonConvert', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel){
      scope.$watch(
        function(){
            return ngModel.$modelValue;
        }, function(newValue, oldValue){
            var value = ngModel.$modelValue
            if (value instanceof Array) return;
            var valueArr = value ? value.split(',') : value;
            if (!valueArr) return;
            for (var i = 0; i < valueArr.length; i++){
              if (valueArr[i]){
                var splitItem = valueArr[i].split("-");
              }
              valueArr[i] = {
                type: splitItem[0] ? splitItem[0] : '',
                name: splitItem[1] ? splitItem[1] : '',
                text:  splitItem[2] ? splitItem[2] : ''
              }
            }
            var result = valueArr;
            ngModel.$setViewValue(result);
        }, true);
    }
  }
})
```

Although the way you have defined what you want may not be scalable or best practise since it maps 0 to type, 1 to name and 2 to text

Example - http://plnkr.co/edit/vtcpiYsTYKq3H2QTupyS?p=preview

Comment: Thank Yang Li, Could you point me out the meaning of scalable or best practise of this directive? I m just noob to angularjs. check my reputation score. :P I've started trying to add-up front-end skill. :-) Anyway, thank for your sharing

Comment: For a user it's extremely complicated to follow the format you have written.  They could easily mess up the positioning so for txt-Glen-Negotiate Price they could write Glen-txt-Negotiate Price in a different order by accident.  I would suggest having 3 different input fields.  Just a UX suggestion anyways.